# TFS doesn't allow me to "Auto-merge"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, merge

I've a Visual studio 2013, with TFS 2010, and currently I've a really annoying issue, when merging one branch on another, I've all the files in conflict, I can't "automerge"(Button "AutoMerge" is always grayed out) even the one where I can basically click on "Merge Changes in Merge Tool" and click "Accept merge".

I'm not sure why Visual Studio doesn't allow me to do an auto-merge, is there something I could do to improve the situation?

**EDIT**
Here how it looks like in the list of files to merges: AutoMerge is not available
[image]

And if I click "Merge Changes In Merge Tool", I got this:
[image]

Additionally: If I compare "Target to base", there 0 changes, if I compare "Source To base", there one line that has changed

Thank you very much

Comment: Merge using the merge tool is always available.  What is the content between the two files and their common ancestor?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Yes, the merge tools is always available. I'm merging some c# files. When I open, sometime there is "0 conflict( 0 remaining)" sometimes there is some: "2 conflict( 0 remaining)"

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, I'm still not sure that I understand the question.  If you have no conflicts (`0 remaining`) then you can't automerge them...

Comment: @J4N: Going by your question & comment what I understand is there are either no conflicts or when there are conflicts they have been resolved - **(2 conflict _(0 remaining)_)**. Since there are no conflicts the Merge features would be disabled.

Comment: @J4N, do other team members get the same issue? You said that sometimes you got "2 conflict( 0 remaining)", maybe there is some version control cache issue cause it. So, please refresh version control cache on the client machine. Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716728(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Vicky Yes they have exactly the same issue. I was having this issue on my previous computer, I got my new computer, did a get latest of the two branches, and were having the same issue, so I guess it's not computer related

Comment: @EdwardThomson I added some screenshot to illustrate